# What are aws lambda artifacts and why do I need to create a S3 bucket to store them?

Tags: aws-lambda

As per the official AWS Lambda [tutorial](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps/nodejs-apig) repository for nodejs, step #1 consists of creating a S3 bucket for lambda *artifacts*.

I cannot find however any definition on what exactly *artifacts* are. Also, I cannot find why I am supposed to store these on S3 buckets.

Comment: As soon as your code is larger than 1mb or something like that you cannot directly create a lambda from it but instead need to package the code, upload it and then reference it when creating / updating the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the Lambda tutorial for nodejs makes use of AWS Cloudformation.

The AWS Cloudformation yml file is considered a byproduct of the development process and therefore, considered an artifact. This yml template file is what needs to be stored in S3 bucket for later rebuilds etc.